# Can be used wildcards in Azure Data Lake Gen 2 Rest API?

Tags: azure, wildcard, azure-data-lake, databricks

I’ve created an Azure Data Lake gen2 filesystem to store and recover data. I’ve loaded my data correctly (one file per day) but, by the time I want to get it using Azure Data Lake gen2 Rest API I can only access one file for each request, so then, if I need for example one month, I have to do a request for each day and merge it in my local machine, while it would be desirable to do that directly in Azure Data Lake gen2.

I know that it can be done with SparkSQL and Wildcards in Databricks, but it would be better if I could use wildcards directly in Azure Data Lake gen2 rest API. I’ve looked for this, but I’ve found documentation not clear. Does everyone know if it is possible, or not, to use something like wildcards in Azure Data Lake gen2 Rest APi?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about merging data and at this time I don't think that we have existing API which does that , but this can achieved by using what you have mentioned and also by using U-SQL and ADF .

Comment: Thanks a lot. I assume it isn’t possible, but I want to clarify before developing another solution. I will check U-SQL and compare with SparkSQL in Data Bricks.